# How to create a factor based on multiple columns for plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to create a barplot with two categories a and b where the colour of the column depends on the category. For both of them, I have strings `x` that determine the category-wise order. A value in `x` can occur in both categories. Now I want to find a way to plot the columns based on two things: First all elements of `x` that belong to category 'a' in their lexicological order, then the same for the elements that belong to category b. Ideally, *without* creating an artificial x column along the lines of `str_c(x, y)`, since they are coded by the legend already. 
Also, faceting is not an option since this is already done for another column.

I found a [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h61Gm.png) that plainly overrides the x-labels with the labels I want, but I'd love to see a less hacky and potentially error-prone way!

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)

df <-
  tibble(
    x = c('1', '0', '0', '1'),
    y = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
    z = runif(4)
  )


df %>%
  arrange(y, x) %>%
  mutate(ordering = str_c(y, '_', x)) %>%
  {
    ggplot(., aes(ordering, z, fill = y)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = pull(., x))
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
df %>%
  arrange(y, x) %>%      
  ggplot(aes(interaction(x, y), z, fill = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = parse_number)
```

[image]

`labels` can also take a function and not only a character vector. Thus, here I pass `parse_number` which parses the input as a number, thereby removing any characters. Instead of creating a new column `ordering` you can use `interaction`.

If you are not using numbers but something else, you can extract the original x-values with

```
my_df %>%
  arrange(y, x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(interaction(x, y, sep = "_"), z, fill = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete("x-axis", 
                   labels = function(x) str_remove(x, "_.*$"))
```

The default `sep` in `interaction` is a dot, which can be matched by `\\.` in the `str_remove` function, but you can also specify any other character, which is not part of your labels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The x-axis is actually a version, so I'd have to resort to regex to extract the version again from the concatenated string? Also, on my data I get warnings, although both columns are reported to be of type character

Comment: Please do not edit my answer with additional information about you problem. Are you sure the two columns are characters? Check with `str(you_data)`. 
Yes, you probably have to resert to regex when your original x and y values are different.

Comment: Sorry, that was by accident! Thanks alot, this was really helpful!